# Using .permutation to brute-force try every possible path for TSP--is there a faster way?

Tags: ruby, recursion, permutation

I have a method, tour_length(tour), that takes a sequence of nodes (a tour) and returns the shortest way to visit those nodes in order (allowing for passing by a node without visiting).  This runs in O(n) time, where n = tour.length.  This is because I have the lengths of the shortest paths between every pair of nodes stored in a hash, so it's just a matter of looking those up and adding them together.

So if I have an array of every node that needs to be in the tour nodes = [a, b, c, d, e], what's the fastest way to find the smallest tour (ordering of nodes) among the set of all permutations of nodes?

One thing that works, but could be faster, is

```
nodes.permutation.min_by{|tour| tour_length(tour)}
```

The problem with doing it this way is that tour_length is being called on ever single full tour.

But note that, for paths

```
b, c, d, a, e
```

and

```
b, c, d, e, a
```

The length of the partial tour

```
b, c, d
```

remains the same, so recalculating it is redundant.

So in light of that, is there a better way I could be using .permutation, or should I just make a recursive method where partial tour lengths are summed together (and so the tour-so-far length can be kept instead of recalculated)?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe I'm not fully understanding what you're doing here, but this looks like the [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). If so, there are a few ways to speed it up (see the link, or google it) but they typically involve finding a solution that is "good enough" rather than the most optimal solution.

Comment: Some shortest path algorithms provide the shortest path from a given node to every other node as a byproduct of giving the shortest path from the given node to another given node.  With such an algorithm you need only enumerate over each (starting, say) node.  If I understand your problem correctly, 'tour' is not the best word, as to me that suggests you have to visit every node, which would make it `n^2` traveling salesman problems.  'Path' is a better descriptor here.

Comment: @neuronaut I'm not looking for a way to speed up TSP, really. I'm limiting myself to brute-force attempting every possible ordering of cities.  Given that, I'm trying to avoid calculating the full length of every tour and instead keep partial tour lengths around.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes, I used Dijkstra's to get the shortest path lengths between all pairs of nodes.  That information is stored.  And so, for a "tour" of [a c d b e] in that order, that would be shortest(a, c) + shortest(c, d) + shortest(d, b), etc.

Comment: On reading your question, I am a little confused.  Lets say you start with a set of nodes, a set of directed links and the distance between each pair of nodes for which there is a link. You want to find the pair of nodes x and y whose shortest path is minimal.  You said not all nodes must be visited.  If there are no restrictions on which nodes are visited, you have n^2 shortest path problems.  However, it appears that a given subset nodes that must be visited, but in no given order, making it a variant of the traveling salesman problem.  Is that correct?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Let me clarify my question.  I have a set of nodes with non-directed weighted edges.  I already know how to calculate the shortest path between any two of the nodes using Dijkstra's.  I do that once and store all the pair-wise shortest path lengths.  Now I need to visit every node in some order.  Say my graph is [a -2- b -4- c].  If my tour (order of visitation) is [a c b], then I'm implicitly passing over b on the way to c. [a c b] is not optimal here.  I want to find a permutation of all n nodes [x1, ..., xn] such that dijkstra(x1, x2) + ... + dijkstra(xn-1, xn) is minimized.

Answer (score 1):

Storing sub-paths is not a scalable way to speed up calculations. There are too many of them. The key-building and storage costs would far outweigh the CPU cost saved in the cached sum-of-distances.

There are ways to enumerate permutations such that each one next in sequence can be calculated from the previous one plus a small change. A good example might be [Steinhaus-Johnson-Trotter algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm)

If you used this algorithm to generate your permutations, then you would know which elements have changed, and only need to adjust by the differences of links added and removed.

However, the cost of running this in pure Ruby will probably outweigh any benefit you gain from not having to sum the entire array, especially as the brute-force approach is going to stop being practical for you at somewhere below 20 nodes. Summing 20 numbers is slow compared to Ruby internal implementation (in C) of `permutation`, but it would be fast compared to re-creating your own version of the same method in Ruby.

Inside `permutation` Ruby seems to be running a similar predictable small-change-at-each-step algorithm, but that is an implementation detail you cannot rely on to be same in all versions, and you have no way to hook your distance recalculation code into how the permutation changes at each step.

---

On brute force limitations - assume you could find a "perfect" algorithm that generated the next permutation in one CPU clock cycle, and then calculated the next distance in a second clock cycle. You use that to check a system with 17 nodes. The time to brute force all 17! permutations on a 3GHz processor might be `2 * 17! / 3 * 10**9 = 237124 seconds` or about 2 and a half days.

---

As OP cannot "view source" on how Ruby implements `permutation` at the top level, here it is for reference:

```
static VALUE
rb_ary_permutation(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE ary)
{
    VALUE num;
    long r, n, i;

    n = RARRAY_LEN(ary);                  /* Array length */
    RETURN_SIZED_ENUMERATOR(ary, argc, argv, rb_ary_permutation_size);   /* Return enumerator if no block */
    rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "01", &num);
    r = NIL_P(num) ? n : NUM2LONG(num);   /* Permutation size from argument */

    if (r < 0 || n < r) {
        /* no permutations: yield nothing */
    }
    else if (r == 0) { /* exactly one permutation: the zero-length array */
        rb_yield(rb_ary_new2(0));
    }
    else if (r == 1) { /* this is a special, easy case */
        for (i = 0; i < RARRAY_LEN(ary); i++) {
            rb_yield(rb_ary_new3(1, RARRAY_AREF(ary, i)));
        }
    }
    else {             /* this is the general case */
        volatile VALUE t0 = tmpbuf(n,sizeof(long));
        long *p = (long*)RSTRING_PTR(t0);
        volatile VALUE t1 = tmpbuf(n,sizeof(char));
        char *used = (char*)RSTRING_PTR(t1);
        VALUE ary0 = ary_make_shared_copy(ary); /* private defensive copy of ary */
        RBASIC_CLEAR_CLASS(ary0);

        MEMZERO(used, char, n); /* initialize array */

        permute0(n, r, p, 0, used, ary0); /* compute and yield permutations */
        tmpbuf_discard(t0);
        tmpbuf_discard(t1);
        RBASIC_SET_CLASS_RAW(ary0, rb_cArray);
    }
    return ary;
}

/*
 * Recursively compute permutations of +r+ elements of the set
 * <code>[0..n-1]</code>.
 *
 * When we have a complete permutation of array indexes, copy the values
 * at those indexes into a new array and yield that array.
 *
 * n: the size of the set
 * r: the number of elements in each permutation
 * p: the array (of size r) that we're filling in
 * index: what index we're filling in now
 * used: an array of booleans: whether a given index is already used
 * values: the Ruby array that holds the actual values to permute
 */
static void
permute0(long n, long r, long *p, long index, char *used, VALUE values)
{
    long i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (used[i] == 0) {
            p[index] = i;
            if (index < r-1) {             /* if not done yet */
                used[i] = 1;               /* mark index used */
                permute0(n, r, p, index+1, /* recurse */
                         used, values);
                used[i] = 0;               /* index unused */
            }
            else {
                /* We have a complete permutation of array indexes */
                /* Build a ruby array of the corresponding values */
                /* And yield it to the associated block */
                VALUE result = rb_ary_new2(r);
                VALUE *result_array = RARRAY_PTR(result);
                const VALUE *values_array = RARRAY_PTR(values);

                for (j = 0; j < r; j++) result_array[j] = values_array[p[j]];
                ARY_SET_LEN(result, r);
                rb_yield(result);
                if (RBASIC(values)->klass) {
                    rb_raise(rb_eRuntimeError, "permute reentered");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, thanks.  What is the ruby process/tool/whatever by which it uses C to do .permutation?  Maybe I should try to use some C.

Comment: Ruby's internals *are* usually written in C, and many of the Array ones use good algorithms known for speed. You can click "Toggle source" to view how Ruby does it at http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-permutation

Comment: clicking that doesn't do anything for me.  Would that be a browser issue or is there some other way to enable it?  I've only been looking at the online rdocs instead of downloading them.

Comment: @user3391564: Possible a browser issue. I will paste it into the answer, but it is not very easy to follow unless you are already familiar with Ruby internals.

Comment: @user3391564: You might also want to look at this answer if you need best solutions for longer than about 10 nodes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159259/optimized-tsp-algorithms

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to (let me quote you) "brute-force attempting every possible ordering of cities" while keeping mind to "avoid calculating the full length of every tour and instead keep partial tour lengths around", then this *IS* the TSP problem, and more specifically it is an application of ["Dynamic Programming"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), an approach used to solve problems by building them up from smaller problems.

If you consider the partial tour lengths the runtime goes from O(n!) (i.e. the number of permutations) to being O(n^2*2^n), which while still being large and hard to scale, *IS* an improvement on literal brute force, and it is, as of 2017, the fastest algorithm to get an *exact* solution to your problem.  The [Bellman-Held-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Held%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) is what you want to learn.  It constructs the optimal exact solution by considering every optimal solution to each possible sub-path in a brute force fashion.