# Maximize the score of circular arrangement of numbers

Tags: algorithm, search, tree, permutation, maximize

I am looking for an efficient algorithm to solve a problem of arranging a circular set of numbers between 1-12 to get the highest score.

The score of an arrangement is given by the sum of the score of all its adjacent pairs

To get the score of an adjacent pair (a,b), the following steps are calculated:

```
1. Find x such that (a+x) mod 12 = b
2. Look up x in a score table
3. The value in the score table at index 'x' is the score of the pair (a,b).
```

This is repeated for every adjacent pair and the sum is the score of the arrangement.

```
Here is an example:

Suppose the score table is [5,4,6,7,2,7,-2,-6,-8,-2,6,12,13]

Consider these numbers: 5, 12, 8, 9

For each adjacent pairs,
the values for x are:   5 -> 12: 7
                        12 -> 8: 8
                        8 -> 9:  1
                        9 -> 5:  8

The values for score[x] are:
                        score[7] = -6
                        score[8] = -8
                        score[1] = 4
                        score[8] = -6

The sum of the score[x] values is: (-6) + (-8) + (4) + (-6) 
                                   = -18
```

The goal is to come up with an algorithm to efficiently arrange the numbers to maximize the score, given the numbers themselves - up to twenty of them between 1 and 12 - and the score table.

Many thanks,

Comment: Problem is.. This looks a lot like a Travelling Salesman Problem (TSP). And solving those optimally isn't always quick. You don't have a large size set, however, and that may be the redeeming factor.

Comment: I suppose I should ask.. Are you looking for an algorithm that finds the maximum score, or a pretty good score?

Comment: I would prefer the maximum score. many thanks.

Comment: In that case, look for exact TSP solvers that allow asymmetric and arbitrary weights. It's not going to be trivial to implement, so if you can leverage a pre-existing library, so much the better. There's a few out there.

Comment: There's some discussion about TSP here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159259/optimized-tsp-algorithms

Comment: im having some trouble seeing how my problem is related to the TSP problem, could you please help me understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem with an exact TSP solver.

Imagine there's a set of cities, each which has a "value". We'll say that the value of a city `x` is `V(x)`. Now imagine that to travel from city `x` to `y` it costs `S(V(y) - v(X) (mod 12))`. Note that `S` is your score table and `V(y) - V(x) (mod 12)` is the value to be looked up in the score table.

The goal of TSP is to find what order you should visit all the cities exactly once to optimize your cost -- in this case, you want to maximize your cost. (Alternatively, you could just make your scoring function negative and minimize your cost.)

That is, TSP will give you a permutation of the set of cities that optimize your score. Since your cities are actually the values you're interesting in permuting, it will give you a permutation of your values that produces an optimal score.

So.. Find a program or library that allows you to specify how much it costs to fly from city `x` to city `y` and then let it run and it'll give you the optimal permutation of your cities -- then you can replace the city IDs with the value (`V(id)`) to get the optimal solution you were looking for.

You could write your own TSP solver as well -- branch & bound techniques look popular.

Comment: since the score also depends on the score between the first and last cities visited, would I need to change the algorithm?

Comment: Shouldn't have to -- the canonical definition is to find a cycle. That means that the last city needs to connect to the first city.