# How would you solve this variation of the Traveling Salesman p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m?

Tags: algorithm, traveling-salesman

Had to do this for work; I gave an approximate solution worked out by hand because I couldn't figure out how to attack it otherwise. I know it's NP-hard, but I'm curious how you would solve the following:

Given 100 locations and a traveling salesman, partition the locations into five groups of 20 locations. Each day's trip will begin from the same central location. Minimize the salesman's total travel distance.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possible approaches:

- Pick a [Heuristic for the TSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Heuristic_and_approximation_algorithms) and modify it so it needs to visit 20 cities out of the 100. Then remove those cities and select 20 from the remaining, and repeat until you select 20 out of 20.
- Use a heuristic to partition the graph into 5 areas. The solve the TSP on each area, with an algorithm like Held-Karp. If you need a better solution, you can play around with the borders of the 5 areas and re-run Held-Karp each time.

See [Optimized TSP Algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159259/optimized-tsp-algorithms) for the Held-Karp Algorithm. It finds the solution in [image: O(n^2 2^n)] time, so it can be used for inputs greater than 20.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a [Vehicle Routing Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_routing_problem) to me. I think you could formulate your problem with the Capacitated Vehicle Routing Problem(CVRP) formulation.

For example, give each vehicle a capacity of 20, and let the demand of each customer be 1. Solving the CVRP would give you a solution with 5 vehicles, each consisting of 20 customers. The routes for these vehicle would represent the routes for your different days.

Solving for small instances can be done optimally by solvers like Gurobi or Cplex.

Answer (score 0):

a starting point could be [lost baggage](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/modelbuilding/blob/master/lostbaggage.mod) in [Model Building](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/model-building-oplcplex-alex-fleischer/)

```
/*
Lost baggage distribution
Problem 27 in Model Building by H.P. Williams edition 5
*/

using CP;

execute
{
  cp.param.timelimit=20;
}

{string} cities=...;

tuple arc
{
  string origin;
  string destination;
}

{arc} allArcs={<o,d> | ordered o,d in cities};

int traveltime[allArcs]=...;

int allowedhorizon=...;

int n=card(cities);
int airport=1;
range visits=2..n;

int timeMatrix[i in 1..n][j in 1..n]=
  ((j!=1) && (i!=j))?((i<j)
  ?traveltime[<item(cities,i-1),item(cities,j-1)>]
  :traveltime[<item(cities,j-1),item(cities,i-1)>]):0;



// sequences of visits 
dvar int x[visits] in visits;

// Is that visit just after an airport visit ?
dvar boolean starts[visits];

// Delivery time to reach that position
dvar int+ deliveryTime[visits] in 0..allowedhorizon;

// how many vans do we use ?
dvar int+ nbVansUsed; 

// max delivery time
dvar int+ maxDeliverytime;

execute
{
  cp.addKPI(nbVansUsed,"how many vans ?");
  cp.addKPI(maxDeliverytime,"max delivery time");
}

minimize staticLex(nbVansUsed,maxDeliverytime);

subject to
{
  
// KPI definitions  
  nbVansUsed==sum(i in visits) starts[i];
  
  maxDeliverytime==max(i in visits) deliveryTime[i];
    
// all cities should be visited once  
  allDifferent(x);
  
// first we start at the airport  
  starts[2]==1;
 
  // compute delivery time
  forall(i in visits) 
     (starts[i]==1) => (deliveryTime[i]==timeMatrix[1][x[i]]);
  forall(i in visits:i!=2)
     (starts[i]!=1) => (deliveryTime[i]==deliveryTime[i-1]+timeMatrix[x[i-1]][x[i]]);
  
  
  
}

execute
{
  writeln("nb vans used : ",nbVansUsed);
  writeln("max delivery time : ",maxDeliverytime);
  writeln("delivery time : ",deliveryTime);
}

/*
which gives
nb vans used : 2
max delivery time : 100
delivery time :  [35 45 57 77 87 100 20 35 45 53 58 69 84 99]
*/
```