# ATSP and TSP exact algorithm in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, optimization, graph

I'm interested in algorithms to solve the Travelling salesman problem in both the symmetric and asymmetric version in a "decent" amount of time.

I've found many industrial solver (such as Concorde), but they are too much complex for my purpose.

So I'm searching for an exact algorithm under the 500 lines (more or less) of code, which takes as input a cost matrix.

The elements of this cost matrix will be random integer between 0 and MAXLENGTH, and elements on the main diagonal (x=y) will be 0, no other assumption could be done on them (for example, the triangle inequality probably won't be satisfied)

Comment: Must those 500 lines completely implement the algorithm, or could they also for example call an external LP solver?

Comment: I would prefer they completely implement the algorithm, but if they call an external solver is better than nothing!

Comment: you might find this interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159259/optimized-tsp-algorithms