# Shortest route algorithm - all nodes with known start and end

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, factorial

I'm trying to find out an algorithm that can generate the shortest route, considering the following rules:

- The start and end points are known and fixed
- Visit all nodes only once without repetition

please refer to the example attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YA1S2.png)

is there's any algorithm that can be used rather than simply calculating the sum of all possible combinations and selecting the lowest value? which is quite useless if you have big numbers.

Regards,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optimized TSP Algorithms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159259/optimized-tsp-algorithms)

Comment: The problem is essentially TSP. Although TSP has the salesman start and end at the same node, you can transform your problem into it -- add an extra node and assign its distance from start and end to be small, and its distance to every other node to be infinity. Then any optimal TSP route starting and ending from the extra node will be a solution (or the reverse of a solution) to your problem. It's an extremely difficult problem to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graph mentioned in problem is directed, Hence, you should have a look at [Travelling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

for detailed explanation and implementation visit [geeksforgeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/travelling-salesman-problem-set-1/)

However this solution is infeasible i.e. NP-Hard, hence you can also take a look at [2-approximation using MST](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/travelling-salesman-problem-set-2-approximate-using-mst/) which might give you an approximation in the answer

Comment: Dijkstra’s algorithm is used to find the shortest path to reach from point A to Z. However in this case, and referring to the rules mentioned, all nodes between start and end points must be part of the route.

Comment: The link you provide is a 2-approximation to TSP using a MST. That's interesting, but I don't think it answers the question as written. It would also be better if you mention that it's an approximation in the answer.

Comment: FIrst part of this answer does not look okay. Lets look at the conditions first: there is start,end node and all nodes has to be traversed. Now with Prims algo you get a tree which has lowest edge cost and you necessarily get a linear kind of tree with start and end node being leaf. Using TSP is the solution here